# finite difference periodic boundary

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, boundary-value-problem, finite-differences

if I have a finite difference approximation of the first derivative on an interval [0,n] such as

$$\frac{u_{j+1}-u_{j-1}}{2\Delta x}$$

and the problem specifies to use periodic boundary conditions. Does that mean that at the left boundary where $j=0$ and $u_{j-1}$ doesn't exist should I replace $u_{j-1}$ with $u_{n}$ which is equal to $u_0$ or I should use $u_{n-1}$?

vice versa at the right boundary where $u_{j+1}$ doesn't exist should I replace it with $u_0$ or $u_1$?

**Update:** The reason I am asking is because I wrote a program to solve the transport equation

$$\frac{du}{dt}=c\frac{du}{dx}$$

using 4th order Runge Kutta time stepping and it causes a phase shift only when the wave crosses the boundary. If I change $u_{j+1}$ to $u_1$ instead of using $u_0$ I don't have the phase shift.

Answer (score 0):

You replace $u_{j-1}$ with $u_n$ and replace $u_{j+1}$ with $u_0$ because your box does not have overlap. i.e. $u_0$ is not the same point as $u_n$. These two points are 'next' to each other across the periodic boundary box.

Comment: they are next to each other but if I understand periodic boundary conditions properly they have the same value which is why I was asking. It seems that I get better results when I assume $u_{j+1} = u_1$ so I'm confused. when I use $u_{j+1} = u_0$ I get a phase shift when it passes the boundary.

Comment: Which ones? $u_n$ is not $u_0$ unless you play a trick like define your grid from 1 to n and use 0 as an overlap.  Is you grid correct? Going from 0 to n gives you $n+1$ segments so $\Delta x = X / (n+1).